# How to access signed Google Storage url created with gsutil?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I think I just created a signed url with gsutil, but it never asked me for the private key's password, rather dropped to a command prompt after I issued the command without any output.

I tried to access the bucket using commondatastorage.googleapis.com as the url, & the secret strings as username/password, but I get 403- forbidden errors.

How do I access my buckets through my S3 browser app?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. What was the gsutil output when you ran signurl? What does the gsutil signurl command have to do with the S3 browser app?

Comment: Yesterday I was under the impression that my app wouldn't access the storage because I didn't have a signed URL, but it wound up being that the app didn't support Google Storage. I've since accessed it via another app. Thanks nevertheless.